# SGActionView Grid Menu

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uialertview, uiactionsheet

i am developing a app in which i am using this grid menu which i downloaded from here https://github.com/sagiwei/SGActionView it is working fine but my problem is that i dont know how i am going to show a nslog when user tap a button from this grid menu. for example if a user tap Facebook the it should NSLog "Facebook Pushed". here is the code which is calling grid.

```
[SGActionView showGridMenuWithTitle:@"Share"
                             itemTitles:@[ @"Facebook", @"Twitter", @"Google+", @"Linkedin",
                                           @"Weibo", @"WeChat", @"Pocket", @"Dropbox" ]
                                 images:@[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"facebook"],
                                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"twitter"],
                                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"googleplus"],
                                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"linkedin"],
                                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"weibo"],
                                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"wechat"],
                                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"pocket"],
                                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"dropbox"]]
                         selectedHandle:nil];
```

please tell me how can i perform a action when pushed a button from this grid (facebook, Twitter or any other) Thanks

Comment: I've never used the SGActionView before, but I guess the selectedHandle is the parameter you want. The parameter must be a SEL type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I checked the library.

The method prototype is

```
+ (void)showGridMenuWithTitle:(NSString *)title
                   itemTitles:(NSArray *)itemTitles
                       images:(NSArray *)images
               selectedHandle:(SGMenuActionHandler)handler
```

and the `SGMenuActionHandler` is block type.

```
typedef void(^SGMenuActionHandler)(NSInteger index);
```

So you can use this like

```
[SGActionView showGridMenuWithTitle:@"Share"
                         itemTitles:@[ @"Facebook", @"Twitter", @"Google+", @"Linkedin",
                                       @"Weibo", @"WeChat", @"Pocket", @"Dropbox" ]
                             images:@[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"facebook"],
                                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"twitter"],
                                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"googleplus"],
                                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"linkedin"],
                                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"weibo"],
                                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"wechat"],
                                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"pocket"],
                                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"dropbox"]]
                     selectedHandle:^(NSInteger index){

                         if(index == 0){
                         }
                         else if(index == 1){
                         },....

                     }];
```

As I commented on your original post, I've never used the library before. It's just a guessing.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote SGActionView.

SGMenuActionHandler is block which give the index of item you tapped. So no guessing, trick14's answer is just right.